# Show component with boolean value in gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean

I have this alert component, and I want it to be displayed only when I pass a true value from a mark down post file (in the frontmatter fields).

```js
import React from 'react'
import { Toast, ToastBody } from 'react-bootstrap'

function alerts({children, alert}){
    
    return (
            <div>
                <Toast className={alert}>
                    <ToastBody>
                        <main>{children}</main>
                    </ToastBody>
                </Toast>           
            </div>
    )
}

alert.defaultProps = {
   alert: "alert-yellow" 
};

export default alerts
```

Displayed in my single post file

```js
import React from 'react'
import Alert from './alerts'

const home = () => {
    return (
    <Alert [HERE I NEED SOMETHING TO MAKE IT VISIBLE] alert="alert-red">
                <h1>bla bla</h1>
                <p>blabla</p>
            </Alert>
            <div>
            blablabla
            </div>
  )          
}
export default home
```

any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div>{condition && <Alert>Warning</Alert>}</div>

// OR in alert component definition 

function Alert({cond}) {
  if (cond) return <div>Alert</div>
  else return null
}
```

Comment: And how can I pass value to my <Aletr cond={true/false} /> inside curly brackets from my .md file? I tryed to pass attributes as simple string (color and text), but it doesn't work with the boolean. like this <Alert cond={post.frontmatter.alert} alert={post.frontmatter.color} /> the second works fine, the first one none.